# Javascript for loop doesn't work (adding numbers to a total)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am using Jasmine for JS testing, and unfortunately I can't get the following test to pass.

```
it('should know the total game score', function() {
    frame1 = new Frame;
    frame2 = new Frame;
    game = new Game;
    frame1.score(3, 4);
    frame2.score(5, 5);
    expect(game.totalScore()).toEqual(17)
});
```

The error message I get is as follows: Error: Expected 0 to equal 17.

The code is as follows:

```
function Game() {
    this.scorecard = []
};


Game.prototype.add = function(frame) {
    this.scorecard.push(frame)
};
// Why is this not working!!???
Game.prototype.totalScore = function() {
    total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < this.scorecard.length; i++)
    {
       total +=this.scorecard[i].rollOne + this.scorecard[i].rollTwo;
    }
    return total;
}; 

function Frame() {};

Frame.prototype.score = function(first_roll, second_roll) {
    this.rollOne = first_roll;
    this.rollTwo = second_roll;
    return this
};

Frame.prototype.isStrike = function() {
    return (this.rollOne === 10);
};

Frame.prototype.isSpare = function() {
    return (this.rollOne + this.rollTwo === 10) && (this.rollOne !== 10)
};
```

Adding the numbers together manually seems to work e.g. total = game.scorecard[0].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo , but the for loop (even though it looks correct) doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Make sure you use `var` to declare variables in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the Frames to your game i guess

```
it('should know the total game score', function () {
    frame1 = new Frame;
    frame2 = new Frame;
    game = new Game;

    // those lines are missing
    game.add(frame1);
    game.add(frame2);

    frame1.score(3, 4);
    frame2.score(5, 5);
    expect(17).toEqual(game.totalScore())
});
```

otherwise, the scorecard-array is empty and the total score is therefore equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I am not pretty sure, but it seems that you are not calling the "Add" method, so no data is added to the scorecard.

Answer (score 0):

missing (so no data is added to the scorecard.)

```
  game.Add(frame1);
   game.Add(frame2);
```